# How to display two form elements next to eachother?

Tags: css, forms, alignment

I'm trying to create a login form where I want the checkbox "Remember me" and the link "Password?" next to eachother, in current situation they are below eachother:

[image]

Code:

```css
.form-group {
    display: block !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    max-width: 75% !important;
    margin-bottom: 5% !important;
}
```

```html
 <div class="form-group">
           <div class="checkbox">
                  <label asp-for="Input.RememberMe">
                      <input asp-for="Input.RememberMe" />
                          @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Input.RememberMe)
                  </label>
            </div>
            <p>
                <a id="forgot-password" asp-page="./ForgotPassword">Password?</a>
            </p>
    </div>
```

How can i achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using any CSS library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the inline-block. After that use padding to center both in the middle.

Because you are using !important many times, I added it also on the class below.

```
.d-inline-block {
  display: inline-block !important;
}

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="checkbox d-inline-block">
    <label asp-for="Input.RememberMe">
      <input asp-for="Input.RememberMe" />
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Input.RememberMe)
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="d-inline-block">
    <a id="forgot-password" asp-page="./ForgotPassword">Password?</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would not recommend `!important`, and as you have created a new class just use a good selector.

Comment: In my comment in the answer I explained why I added the !important. Using it is not best practice and not recommended because any good selector cannot override the !imprtant. Without knowing the other css I added it to be sure it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change 'display: block' to 'display: flex' in 'form-group' class selectir

Answer (score 0):

The `div` and `paragraph` elements are [block elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) by default.

In order to render these elements next to each other, you need to ensure the `div class="checkbox"` is made to be an alternative - I would recommend using `display:inline-block;`.

You could clean up your markup and completely remove the `<p>` tag from your form and just keep the hyperlink. Check out the snippet below.

```css
.form-group {
    display: block !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    max-width: 75% !important;
    margin-bottom: 5% !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
           <div class="checkbox" style="display:inline-block">
                  <label asp-for="Input.RememberMe">
                      <input asp-for="Input.RememberMe" />
                          @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Input.RememberMe)
                  </label>
            </div>
                <a id="forgot-password" asp-page="./ForgotPassword">Password?</a>
    </div>
```